# Sieve of Eratosthenes - bitwise optimization problem

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I guess every one of you has encountered the optimization code of Eratosthenes sieve with bitwise operations. I am trying to wrap my head around it and I have a question on one of the operations in this implementation. Here is the code from GeeksforGeeks:

```c
bool ifnotPrime(int prime[], int x) { 
    // checking whether the value of element 
    // is set or not. Using prime[x/64], we find 
    // the slot in prime array. To find the bit 
    // number, we divide x by 2 and take its mod 
    // with 32. 
    return (prime[x / 64] & (1 << ((x >> 1) & 31))); 
} 

// Marks x composite in prime[] 
bool makeComposite(int prime[], int x) { 
    // Set a bit corresponding to given element. 
    // Using prime[x/64], we find the slot in prime  
    // array. To find the bit number, we divide x 
    // by 2 and take its mod with 32. 
    prime[x / 64] |= (1 << ((x >> 1) & 31)); 
} 

// Prints all prime numbers smaller than n. 
void bitWiseSieve(int n) { 
    // Assuming that n takes 32 bits, we reduce 
    // size to n/64 from n/2. 
    int prime[n / 64]; 

    // Initializing values to 0 . 
    memset(prime, 0, sizeof(prime)); 

    // 2 is the only even prime so we can ignore that 
    // loop starts from 3 as we have used in sieve of 
    // Eratosthenes . 
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) { 

        // If i is prime, mark all its multiples as 
        // composite 
        if (!ifnotPrime(prime, i)) 
            for (int j = i * i, k = i << 1; j < n; j += k) 
                makeComposite(prime, j); 
    } 

    // writing 2 separately 
    printf("2 "); 

    // Printing other primes 
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) 
        if (!ifnotPrime(prime, i)) 
            printf("%d ", i); 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() { 
    int n = 30; 
    bitWiseSieve(n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

So my questions are:

1. what is the meaning of `(prime[x/64] & (1 << ((x >> 1) & 31))` and more specifically `(1 << ((x >> 1) & 31));`
2. in `prime[x/64]` why do we divide by `64` and not with `32`, when we work with  32 bit integer;
3. Is `int prime[n/64]` correct if `n < 64`?

Comment: Presumably because the sieve is representing only odd numbers and does not waste space on the even numbers. You can deal with even numbers trivially. Therefore you can represent a range of 64 numbers in 32 bits.

Comment: OT: `bool makeComposite(...){...}` --> `void makeComposite(...){...}`

Comment: This code is not very readable, take a look on [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ODZ2TL4VgjJv6b0c) which is C++ and it is written to be more readable. Basically algorithm is same, but information is not stored in bits (there is no point in case constexpr). Change `std::array` to `std:vector` and you have version, where flags are stored in single bits.

Comment: Regarding question 3: it's only correct (in C, not in C++) if n is a multiple of 64. Geeksforgeeks is well known for not being particularly good or reliable. Staying away from it is probably a good idea.

Comment: @molbdnilo Corner case: `int prime[n/64];` invalid in C when `n==0` or less than 0, even though it is a multiple of 64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `makeComposite()` should have return type `void`.
- `(1 << ((x >> 1) & 31))` has undefined behavior if `x == 63` because `1 << 31` overflows the range of type `int`. You should use `1U` or preferably `1UL` to ensure 32 bits.
- it would be simpler to shift the table entry and mask the last bit: `return (prime[x / 64] >> ((x >> 1) & 31)) & 1;`
- instead of assuming that type `int` has 32 bits, you should use `uint32_t` as the type for the bit array.
- the array `int prime[n / 64];` is too short if `n` is not a multiple of 64. Use `uint32_t prime[n / 64 + 1];` instead. This is a problem for your example as `n = 30`, so the array is created with a length of `0`.
- `ifnotPrime(n)` only returns a valid result for odd values. It might be better and more readable to change this function and name it `isOddPrime()`.

Regarding your questions:

> what is the meaning of `(prime[x/64] & (1 << ((x >> 1) & 31))` and more specifically `(1 << ((x >> 1) & 31))`?

`x` is first divided by 2 (shift right one position) because only odd numbers have a bit in the array, then the result is masked with 31 to keep the 5 low order bits as the bit number in the word. For any unsigned value `x`, `x & 31` is equivalent to `x % 32`. `x / 64` is the word number where to test this bit.

As mentioned above, `1` is an `int` and thus should not be shifted left by 31 positions. Using `1UL` ensures that the type has at least 32 bits and can be shifted by 31 positions.

> in `prime[x/64]` why do we divide by `64` and not with `32`, when we work with 32-bit integer?

The bits in the array correspond to odd numbers, so a 32-bit word contains primeness information for 64 numbers: 32 even numbers that are known to be composite and 32 odd numbers for which the corresponding bit it set if the number is composite.

> Is `int prime[n/64]` correct if `n < 64`?

Not it is not, it is incorrect if `n` is not a multiple of `64`: the size expression should be `(n + 63) / 64`, or better `int prime[n/64 + 1]`

---

Here is a modified version, where you can pass a command line argument:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool isOddPrime(const uint32_t prime[], unsigned x) {
    // checking whether the value of element
    // is set or not. Using prime[x/64], we find
    // the slot in prime array. To find the bit
    // number, we divide x by 2 and take its mod
    // with 32.
    return 1 ^ ((prime[x / 64] >> ((x >> 1) & 31)) & 1);
}

// Marks x composite in prime[]
void makeComposite(uint32_t prime[], unsigned x) {
    // Set a bit corresponding to given element.
    // Using prime[x/64], we find the slot in prime
    // array. To find the bit number, we divide x
    // by 2 and take its mod with 32.
    prime[x / 64] |= (1UL << ((x >> 1) & 31));
}

// Prints all prime numbers smaller than n.
void bitWiseSieve(unsigned n) {
    // Assuming that n takes 32 bits, we reduce
    // size to n/64 from n/2.
    uint32_t prime[n / 64 + 1];

    // Initializing values to 0 .
    memset(prime, 0, sizeof(prime));

    // 2 is the only even prime so we can ignore that
    // loop starts from 3 as we have used in sieve of
    // Eratosthenes .
    for (unsigned i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        // If i is prime, mark all its multiples as composite
        if (isOddPrime(prime, i)) {
            for (unsigned j = i * i, k = i << 1; j < n; j += k)
                makeComposite(prime, j);
        }
    }

    // writing 2 separately
    if (n >= 2)
        printf("2\n");

    // Printing other primes
    for (unsigned i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (isOddPrime(prime, i))
            printf("%u\n", i);
    }
}

// Driver code
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned n = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 1000;
    bitWiseSieve(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Corner: `for (unsigned i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)` fails for large prime `n` near `UINT_MAX` due to `i*i` overflow.  Recommend `for (unsigned i = 3; i <= n/i; i += 2)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: corner case where `i * i` overflows if `n` is too close to `UINT_MAX`: yes, that's a good point, but only for very large values of `n` which would cause `int32_t prime[(n + 63) / 64];` to fail anyway.

Comment: I changed that to `n / 64 + 1`, which is good enough for this case.

Comment: I agree with you on the goal, yet I would prefer a solution that does not use division. Computing the square root of `n` with a fast converging method might be best.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `ifnotPrime` deserved a note indeed :)

Comment: Seeking a full range alternative for `for (unsigned i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {` without a `/` might make for a nice question.  Your `isqrt(n)` idea is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

1)`x%32` is equivalent to `x&31`: a logical and on the least significant 5 bits. so basically `((x>>1)&31)` implies `((x/2)%32)`. and `1<<x` means `2^x` so what you are asking is `2^((x/2)%32)`.

2)One optimization in implementation is, it skipped all even numbers altogether.

3)`n` can less than 64

Comment: i dont understand the answer of q(3

Comment: `n` is number less than which you are trying to find all the prime numbers if it is less than `64` it will do it in O(1) time without using bitwise optimisation.

Comment: Detail : "x%32 is equivalent to x&31" is true when `x >= 0` as used by OP, yet is not the same when `x < 0`

Comment: If `n < 64`, `int prime[n / 64];` is invalid.

Comment: `int prime[n/64]` is equivalent to `int prime[0]`  if `n<64` which is valid statement although it is not used for computation of primes that will be calculated via brute force for `n<64` and in my answer i have written `n can be less than 64` which is true